# return from incompatible pointer type warning in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm not really familiar with C and when I was trying to use C to build a linked list, I ran into a little problem and would like to have someone clarify it for me.

Here's my code so far:

```
typedef struct {
struct dlinkNode_t *next;
struct dlinkNode_t *prev;
void *value;
} dlinkNode_t;

dlinkNode_t* getNext(dlinkNode_t *ptr){
/**return the next node of the node pointed by ptr. Return NULL if next element*/
return ptr->next;
```

When I tried to compile it I got the following warning:

```
"warning: return from incompatible pointer type"
```

I defined dlinkNode_t to be the type of my linked list's node, and each node has 2 pointers pointing forward and backward. Should I define the return type of getNext to be:

```
struct dlinkNode_t*
```

But this seems to violate the purpose of typedef, because I want to define dlinkNode as a new type. Any help would be good.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.. `struct` must have name when you are using same `struct` pointer inside it ....

```
typedef struct dlinkNode {
struct dlinkNode *next;
struct dlinkNode *prev;
void *value;
} dlinkNode_t;

dlinkNode_t* getNext(dlinkNode_t *ptr){
/**return the next node of the node pointed by ptr. Return NULL if next element*/
return ptr->next;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
typedef struct dlinkNode_t {
    struct dlinkNode_t *next;
    struct dlinkNode_t *prev;
    void *value;
} dlinkNode_t;
```